# How can I return data from yyparse?

Tags: parsing, yacc, bison

I'm implementing a line-by-line data parser, and it works by calling yyparse in a loop. Only problem is that I have no way of extracting the data, other than a global variable, which I'd prefer to avoid. Any tips?

Comment: what data are you trying to extract? All the work should be done through the actions called when rules are completed. Also in my experience, bad programming styles like using gotos and global variables happen a lot when using yacc/bison and lex/flex. I don't believe there is a way around it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use bison's `%parse-param` directive to add argument(s) for yyparse, which can include a pointer (or in C++ a reference) to some variable or data structure that can be written to in the actions in the parser.